# Eclipse: Maven build error in child pom for custom properties in parent pom

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am working on a maven based project. I have a parent pom file for the parent module and a child pom file for the child module. In parent module I am using a custom property (databaseType) and it is declared in parent pom.

```
<properties>
    <databaseType>${databaseType}</databaseType>
</properties>
```

While building the application, I am passing it as `-D` argument and its building successfully. However, when I am creating a maven project in eclipse, I am getting below error in child pom (Though the maven build is happening fine)

```
Project build error: Resolving expression: '${databaseType}': Detected 
the following recursive expression cycle in 'databaseType': [databaseType]
```

What could be the issue? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What version of eclispe and the maven plugin are you using? We've run into many problems using m2e...

Comment: I am using eclipse _Juno_ and maven version is _3.0.4_

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that both the argument you pass with `-D` and the property have the same name. If you provide the argument, it works because when maven resolves the expression it first finds the provided argument by `-D databaseType` and then assigns that value to the `<databaseType>` property. If the argument is missing, maven tries to resolve the expression but only finds the definition of the `<databaseType>` property in the same pom, which creates a circle.

Maven and Eclipse are either using different approaches to resolve variables here (which might a bug in eclipse) or it's caused by some misconfiguration. I would guess that passing the variable with `-D` is not working in Eclipse for some reason.

The example doesn't really do anything anyways. If `${databaseType}` is available, you shouldn't need to explicitly define the property again. Or use a different property name in the parent pom if it makes sense, like this:

```
<properties>
    <databaseType>${defaultDatabaseType}</databaseType>
</properties>
```

This doesn't help if the argument is missing though. I would use the enforcer plugin to make sure it the property is defined.

Comment: _It looks like it is not using the parent's property because you are redefining databaseType in the child pom_

I am not redefining the databaseType property in child pom, its present in only parent pom.

Comment: @SomnathMusib Ok, in that case I think the databaseType argument is missing in eclipse. I've updated the answer